# castle windsor wcf service and DependencyResolverException

Tags: castle-windsor, wcffacility

I use the AsWcfService() to host my WCF service. When I get an DependencyResolverException because one component is misconfigured, the container somehow swallows the DependencyResolverException. It even does not show up in the ouptut window.
My windows service starts and I do not recognize that the service is not running until the client gets a EndpointNotFoundException.

How can I detect this problem on startup of my windows service? I want to fail as fast as possible.

How can I delay and control the start of the services? I want to start certain services on demand, but still want to register them in my installers. The container automagically starts all registered services, by default.

Thanks!